# Nightmare JS cannot get Button Element

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I am trying to do some simple nightmare.js.
The problem is that I cannot get one specific button.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
  .goto('https://account.parkmobile.com/login')
  .wait(3000)
  .type('#username', '')
  .wait(2000)
  .type('#login_password', '')
  .wait(2000)
  .evaluate(function() {
    let loginBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block")
    for (let loginBtn of loginBtns) loginBtn.click()
        })

  .wait(4000)
  .evaluate(function() {
  let newSessions = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary add-button close-panel-margin ng-star-inserted")
  for (let newSession of newSessions) newSession.click()
      })
  .wait(4000)
  .type("#zone > div > input", "21789")
  .wait(3000)
  .click("#zone > div > div > div > div")  
  .wait(4000)
  .evaluate(function() {
    let newStarts= document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block ng-tns-c36-26")
    for (let newStart of newStarts) newStart.click()
        })
  .wait(3000)
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

I am talking about this line:

```
  .evaluate(function() {
    let newStarts= document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-block ng-tns-c36-26")
    for (let newStart of newStarts) newStart.click()
        })
```

[image]

Could it be that it has to do something with this text:
`_ngcontent-uei-c203`
after the `<button`

Maybe someone can help clicking on "Start this parking" button. :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure you want to share your userid and login details here?

Comment: Please elaborate on `I cannot get one specific button`; Is there an error? Does it not loop? Have you verified that `newStarts` is as expected?

Comment: why are you not using wait with the element you are waiting for? `.wait('[data-qa="button.start"]')`

Comment: @epascarello I will try it and keep you updated. Thank you

Comment: going for the data-qa worked out 

Thanks everyone!